# SQL Server - Global Variable Resets in Nested While Loop

Tags: sql, sql-server, while-loop, scope, sql-server-2016

I'm having a global Variable, which get increment in the Nested While Loop. In Each Iteration it Resets the Value to `1` (i.e., Initially Initialized Value).

Sample Re-produce able Code:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @GlobalCounter INT = 1;
DECLARE @CounterOne INT = 1;
DECLARE @CounterTwo INT = 1;

WHILE(@CounterOne <= 10)
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Outer Loop:';
    PRINT @GlobalCounter;

    DECLARE @SerialInfo table
    (
        [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        [SNumber] [NVARCHAR](20) NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY ([Id])
    );

    SET @CounterTwo = 1;
    WHILE(@CounterTwo <= 10)
    BEGIN

        DECLARE @SerialNumber NVARCHAR(20);
        SET @SerialNumber = 'SRL: ' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), @GlobalCounter);

        INSERT INTO @SerialInfo([SNumber]) VALUES (@SerialNumber);

        SET @GlobalCounter = @GlobalCounter + 1;
        SET @CounterTwo = @CounterTwo + 1;
    END

    SET @CounterTwo = 1;
    WHILE(@CounterTwo <= 10)
    BEGIN
        SET @SerialNumber = '';
        SELECT @SerialNumber = [SNumber] FROM @SerialInfo WHERE [Id] = @CounterTwo;
        PRINT @SerialNumber;
        SET @CounterTwo = @CounterTwo + 1;
    END

    SET @CounterOne = @CounterOne + 1;
END
```

Kindly assist me in terms of Global Variable Scope and its value. How to achieve the Expected Results

```
SRL: 1
SRL: 2
SRL: 3
.
.
.
SRL: 99
SRL: 100
```

[Resultant Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dpum6.jpg)

Comment: What results are you currently getting?

Comment: not sure what the problem is when i check to see whats in the results are in @serialinfo I get the expected results you posted. 

we will need to know what results you are getting.

Comment: @Jonathan I added a Screenshot which contains the Result of the above said SQL Query.

Comment: The problem isn't the global counter - it's the declaration of the table variable. If you do `select * from @SerialInfo` after the loop you should see the problem. There's probably a better way to do this entire job without loops or table variables, if you could describe the overall objective, which I assume this is *part* of a proposed solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In T-SQL, variable declarations do *not* participate in control flow. So just because `declare @SerialInfo table...` appears inside the loop, that doesn't mean that `@SerialInfo` is *reinitialized* as an empty table each time through the loop.

As soon as a variable declaration is encountered as each batch is being parsed, the variable name becomes valid from that point onwards until the end of the batch.

E.g. this works:

```
if 1=0
begin
    declare @a int
end
set @a = 15
print @a
```

Unfortunately, your current code is so *procedurally* based that it's difficult to see what *actual task* you're trying to accomplish and make a recommendation for fixing it. But it probably doesn't require loops and relying on generated `IDENTITY` values.

---

Hopefully, from the above, it's clear what you're seeing - `@SerialInfo` ends up containing 100 rows with all of the values you apparently wanted. But since your `print` loop only queries the first 10 rows of the table, it continues to output the same 10 rows that were inserted the first time that the outer loop ran.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is with that query you provided, that you are querying only first 10 [SNumber]

```
WHILE(@CounterTwo <= 10)
BEGIN
    SET @SerialNumber = '';
    SELECT @SerialNumber = [SNumber] FROM @SerialInfo WHERE [Id] = @CounterTwo;
```

Check that query if it matches your business logic:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @GlobalCounter = 1;
DECLARE @CounterOne INT = 1;
DECLARE @CounterTwo INT = 1;

WHILE(@CounterOne <= 10)
BEGIN
    DECLARE @SerialInfo table
    (
        [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        [SNumber] [NVARCHAR](20) NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY ([Id])
    );

    SET @CounterTwo = 1;
    WHILE(@CounterTwo <= 10)
    BEGIN

        DECLARE @SerialNumber NVARCHAR(20);
        SET @SerialNumber = 'SRL: ' + cast(@globalCounter as varchar)

        INSERT INTO @SerialInfo([SNumber]) VALUES (@SerialNumber);
        SET @GlobalCounter = @GlobalCounter + 1;
        SET @CounterTwo = @CounterTwo + 1;
    END
    SET @CounterOne = @CounterOne + 1;
END
set @CounterTwo = 1
WHILE(@CounterTwo <= @GlobalCounter)
BEGIN
    SET @SerialNumber = '';
    SELECT @SerialNumber = [SNumber] FROM @SerialInfo WHERE [Id] = @CounterTwo;
    PRINT @SerialNumber;
    SET @CounterTwo = @CounterTwo + 1;
END
```

Comment: Not at all. The '@SerialInfo' table variable always contains 10 records.